# using colordata on a list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color

want to plot some rays with "warm" colors, so I started with a radial ray with a few points.

```
ray = Flatten[ Table[{r Cos[Theta], r Sin[Theta]}, {r, 0, 1, 0.1}, {Theta, 0.7, 0.7}], 1];
```

After reading mathematica help I believe the result of this command

```
ColorData[{"SiennaTones", "Reverse"}][#/(Max[ray[[All, 2]]])] & /@ ray[[All, 2]]
```

is going to inform me of the colors that the 11 points in the initial list will have when using that command as an option to ListPlot. That command produces an array of colors covering the whole range of SiennaTones, which range from whiteish to brown. So I do it like this:

```
ListPlot[
   ray, 
   PlotStyle -> (
      {PointSize[0.01], ColorData[{"SiennaTones", "Reverse"}][#]} & /@ ray[[All, 2]]
   )
]
```

And all I get are whiteish points. Can anybody kindly help me?

Thanks,

Ruth

Answer (score 3):

You are close:

```
ray = Flatten[ Table[{r Cos[Theta], r Sin[Theta]}, {r, 0, 1, 0.1}, {Theta, 0.7, 0.7}], 1];
style = ColorData[{"SiennaTones", "Reverse"}][#/(Max[ray[[All, 2]]])] & /@ ray[[All, 2]];

ListPlot[ Style[ #1, #2]& @@@ Transpose@{ray,style} ]
```

[image: Colored Rays]

Or shorter:

```
ListPlot[ List /@ ray, PlotStyle -> style ]
```

The problem with what you have tried is, that a list of points is treated as one *set* which only has *one* color. Thus you have to make each point a list of its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very informative answer. I used to learn a lot with this forum. Love to be back into business.

Comment: @Ruth Great to hear that I could help. Do not forget to (eventually) accept an answer. ;-)